How to extract all chapters numbers from a PDF book using Java
Actually I am writing a PDF reader in Java. Firstly I am gathering the basic PDF information to store in DB like author, title etc. Although I was able to find out the basic information using PDFBox library
but now I want to find out all the page numbers where each chapter starts, so I can store them in DB and keep record of each chapter as individual (use case: Suppose I want start any specific chapter as per user request then I must be able to choose it from the PDF Book directly by referring the page number). This is the challenge to find out the page number where a chapter starts in the PDF book, because in PDF there can not be any specific starting Name or header of a chapter these can be different like 'Chapter 1', '0x100 Introduction', or 'Introduction' etc. This the challenge to figure out all the chapter's starting page no. from the book and store it in the DB.
I have used PDFBox Java library to do this but still not found any possible solution.
One possible solution is by processing the index page of book in the program but there are few challenges.

How to identify the index page of PDF?

On Index page there are other pages aslo apart from chapters.

If we read any page using PDFBox library and convert it to text then some time it may contain any irrelevant information at starting of the page not just the content visible on the page.



That is the thing how I could identify through code where does a chapter starts, because in pdf there can be any name or pattern of starting the chapter for different PDF book. Thanks.

Right.  That's the answer.  You can't.  For specific books, you can probably identify a pattern, but there is no answer in the general case because there are no rules.

Are your PDFs tagged? Then the structure information in the PDF can help. Otherwise all you can have are heuristics.

Some PDF may tagged, but not all PDF. Can you provide a sample code for tagged PDF?

you can use jpdfbookmarks to export bookmarks from pdf file. (As someone said, if the pdf file itself has bookmarks.)
